# Separate long numbers by 3 digits

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

Is there a easy way to transform 1000000 in 1.000.000? A regex or string format in asp.net, c#

Comment: is it a number or a string to begin with?

Comment: If you're using . instead of , to accommodate local culture, see my answer below...

Comment: Peronal note: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ToString` together with a formatting string and a format provider that uses '.' as a group separator and defines that the number should be grouped in 3-digit groups (which is not the case for all cultures):

```
int number = 1000000;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("N0", new NumberFormatInfo()
                                            {
                                                NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 },
                                                NumberGroupSeparator = "."
                                            }));
```

Comment: Cool does not always imply correct. egrunin's solution is far better as that is the proper "global" way! Of course, we don't really know what the OP wanted :)

Answer (score 8):

```
1000000.ToString("N0")
```

Comment: value.ToString("N0").Replace(',','.'); does the trick. Also comma or dot comes from system separator setting. For any case I'm replacing comma with dot. Thank you.

Comment: Won't work in India though (they don't group in 3-digit groups)

Comment: @Fredrik, it will work according to regional settings, whatever they are

Comment: exactly, and the title of the question is *"Separate long numbers by 3 digits"*. If your code runs in the 'hi-IN' culture the output will be `10,00,000`.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're asking about culture-specific formatting. This is the Spanish way, for example:

```
1000000.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ToString("N")` after will convert 1000000 to 1,000,000. Not sure about . though

Comment: That will probably depend on culture settings. In Turkey it should default to dots rather than commas, so you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Use ToString with numeric format string after reading into an integer. I believe the one you are looking for is "N" and its relatives.

MSDN page about numeric format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx